# Retrieve data from XML

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I have a soap web service which returns given response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="">
<soap:Body>
  <ns2:getRegisterValuesResponse xmlns:ns2="">
     <return>
        <id>11931</id>
        <value>0</value>
     </return>
     <return>
        <id>11946</id>
        <value>0</value>
     </return>
     <return>
        <id>11961</id>
        <value>0</value>
     </return>
  </ns2:getRegisterValuesResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How do i retrieve given integers inside a java method?

Here's my method. The idea is to get the database update every X minutes with given ids and values.

```
public class RegisterLog implements Job {

public void execute(final JobExecutionContext ctx)
        throws JobExecutionException {
    SimulatorSOAPClientSAAJ sc=new SimulatorSOAPClientSAAJ();
    SOAPMessage msg = sc.sOAPConnect();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        msg.writeTo(out);
    } catch (SOAPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());
    System.out.println(strMsg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using DOM XML PARSER** http://www.w3schools.com/dom/default.asp

**Imports**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.*;
```

**Code**

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(bais);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("return");
for (int i=0;i<nList.getLength();i++) {
   Node nNode = nList.item(i);
   if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      Element curElement = (Element) nNode;
      int id = Integer.parseInt(curElement.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getTextContent()); 
      String value = curElement.getElementsByTagName("value").item(0).getTextContent();   
   }
}
```

Comment: Works great. Thumbs up.

Comment: @PiotrCzapla,Thanks! Love to help.